# can I use several usernames in maven settings.xml file?

Tags: maven, nexus

our Nexus repository is configured to use repository-target permissions: 
user1 can deploy to com.company.group1, 
user2 can deploy to com.company.group2, etc.

can we have both user1 and user2 credentials for the same Maven repository in .m2/settings.xml file? will Maven try them both if permission is denied for one of them?

Comment: As far as i know No. Cause the authentication mechanism is based on on URL's or id's and not on groupId inside the content. Why do you need such thing to have different authentications within a single repository ? Otherwise you should use staging repositories (commericial release).

Comment: The OP's use case is described in a [Sonatype blog post](http://www.sonatype.com/people/2010/02/how-to-partition-nexus-repositories-targets-privileges-and-roles/) which explains how to use repository targets to partition a single Nexus repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could e.g. use different profiles for each user and set user name and password as properties in those profiles. Then you could activate the profile depending on what user you want to work as at the moment. You could also set one of the profiles to be active by default so that you don't have to always use a profile name in your invocations.

Another way to do it would be to have separate settings.xml files for the users and specify the desired one with the -s flag for the maven invocation.

Comment: I thought of the multiple settings files, but thought if someone had made the effort to section off a repository using repository targets then the passwords should be secured too.  Curious, how are you keeping user1 from deploying to the repo with user2's credentials?

Comment: I just dont tell user1 the credentials of user2... kidding aside I think you are mixing up roles and users. A person should only have access to one credential set (username + password) and then that user should be granted the different roles and access rights necessary..

Comment: I've done some Nexus config so I'm familiar with roles vs users. If I'm user1 and I've been granted the role/privilege to deploy to repo-target X only, while user2 has been granted appropriate roles to deploy to target Y, what would stop me from running `mvn -s user2settings.xml deploy` and putting an artifact in a repo I haven't been authorized for in Nexus?

Comment: if you have access to user2settings you are effectively using the user2 credentials and as such you can deploy. You as a person (=user1) should not have access to the user2 settings..

Comment: Exactly!  Which is why the settings.xml file is typically stored in a subdirectory of an individual user account's home directory.  :-)  If multiple users are sharing a single login account it's harder to protect file contents.  Care must be taken to make sure user's can't access the credentials in someone else's settings.xml file, or the protections configured in Nexus are useless.

Comment: You mentioned the root of the problem yourself... multiple user are sharing a single login account. That should never happen!

Answer (score 2):

I use properties in distributionManagement, like-

```
  <distributionManagement>
    <repository>
      <id>releases</id>
      <url>${url.releases}</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
      <id>snapshots</id>
      <url>${url.snapshots}</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
    <site>
      <id>site</id>
      <url>${url.site}</url>
    </site>
  </distributionManagement>
```

My settings.xml has profiles that define these properties for target repositories. The `<id>` are matched with the `<server>` in the settings.xml, so you could use different `<id>` for different username/password/repository combination. In settings.xml, setup   `<activeProfiles>` to the default profile you need for your deployment. When you need to switch to a different profile, you can do so on the command line.

Answer (score 1):

You can't mix credentials in the same `settings.xml` file, as far as I know; seems this would be a large security hole.  Each user should have his own login on your build machine; then each person has his own `.m2/settings.xml` and `.m2/settings-security.xml` files (you need the latter to [encrypt passwords](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-encryption.html)).  Each user adds `<server>` entries with ids matching the ids in the `<distributionManagement>` section for the projects being deployed.